# jQuery display value when dropdown menu is used

Tags: jquery

I used to have a text input in place of the dropdown, where you would type in a number. However, I wanted something a little more logical, so I converted it to a dropdown. My jQuery code only works if I use a text-input, unfortunately.

How would I make it work in this situation?

Here's my code: http://slexy.org/view/s2rNXE3OcO

One last thing - how would I fix the height of the dropdown menu to around 8 values and have a scrollbar for the rest of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `change()` event handler that sets the display you are referrencing an input with a name of select. I think that selector should instead just be `$('#element_3')` as can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dSLcU/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="element_3" id="element_3">
```

is given by you

```
$('input[name=select]').change(function(){
   $('#select').text($(this).val());
});
```

is this a mistake?

Comment: another mistake #
$('#element_1').bind('keydown keyup kepress', function(){
   $('#advertiserNameDisplay').html($(this).val());
}); it's keypress!